# In bike geometry, what is 'RC Length'?

Tags: geometry

For example, seen on the [Reid Cycles website](https://www.reidcycles.com.au/collections/cyclocross/products/reid-granite-4-0-grey?variant=30327189569616)

Comment: Bike geometry terms are mostly standardized, but there can be variations in what they are called. On geometry charts for US road bikes, I don’t recall ever seeing the term rear center length. Most people would give the chain stay length. I agree with Michael’s answer that they are most likely synonyms. PS, i agree that the terms can be confusing, but I have actually seen geo charts that are positively cryptic, like older Colnago and even current Pinarello charts. Best practice is usually to give a diagram, which Reid Cycles failed to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Rear Center Length**

It’s the distance from the rear hub to the bottom bracket. More or less the chainstay length.

Unfortunately Reid Cycles doesn’t have a diagram of what and where exactly they are measuring. For example top tube length could be the actual tube length or a “virtual” top tube length (like in the diagram below) if the top tube were completely horizontal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!
I thought stack and reach were quite important measurements, but Reid cycles omit them

Comment: Yes, that’s their biggest mistake. All the other measurements are more or less meaningless (at least for non-frame builders) except maybe front wheel trail (for how stable it steers) and seat stay length (for how much space you have for panniers).